# what does "width" mean for pprint in python?

Tags: python

I don't understand what "width" means.

For example, in case of the following code,
Why is the list devided at the "width=29"?

code:

```
import pprint

list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

pprint.pprint(list, width=30)
pprint.pprint(list, width=29)
```

result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9]
```

Comment: btw never create python variables called `list` or `dict` those are keywords. That's a bad habit, whenever you overshadow those, you might run into problems. Follow the semantics when calling variable, not type. For a generic list variable I might use something like `l`  or 'list_1'

Comment: @Serge: `list` and `dict` are **not** keywords, that's why you can redefine them. They are the names of some built-in type and should still consider off-limits because redefining them can cause hard to debug problem and confuses many folks who assume what they mean (because nobody's supposed to redefine them).

Comment: Try reading the documentation.

Comment: Thank you all.

I could understand what you all comment.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @martineau - I was trying to be more accessible to the poster, yet, my bad, you are right, one even cannot shadow the keyword, those are protected. By the way declaring variable called `l` is against pep8 style recommendation, I take that back too.

Comment: @Serge: Giving them misinformation isn't doing them any favors. `;¬)` No worries, it's actually a minor point because the bottomline is the same — don't try to redefine them even when Python will let you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

> The desired output width is constrained using the width parameter; the
> default is 80 characters. If a structure cannot be formatted within
> the constrained width, a best effort will be made. If compact
> [parameter] is false (the default) each item of a long sequence will
> be formatted on a separate line.

So if a data structure, which is in your case a list of 10 integers  does not fit 29 characters, the default "best effort" strategy to keep thing pretty yet within 29 characters width places each element of the oversized list on a separate line.

The default strategy seem pretty enough to me yet if you would like to squeeze more elements per line for more compact reorientation, set `compact=True`.

In the same time 30 characters width is enough to pretty-print the whole list in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

> The desired output width is constrained using the *width* parameter; the default is 80 characters. If a structure cannot be formatted within the constrained width, a best effort will be made.

That means if the list in one line is bigger than the `width` argument, it would split the values all to different lines.